# changing rewriteBatchedStatements with play, hibernate and mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, bulkinsert, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to optimize for bulk inserts via play(1.2.4)+mysql.
I saw some posts talking about adding the following to jdbc configuration (adding it to the connection string): useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useCompression=true

I've tried to do:

```
db=mysql://root@localhost/data?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useCompression=true
```

But I get this error:

```
A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, The connection property 'useCompression' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true?useUnicode=yes' is not in this set.
```

I also tried to use db=jdbc:mysql://....

Still no luck.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Play automatically appends the MySQL connection string with the following:

```
?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
```

So I am guessing your connection string ends up invalid as there is now two sets of parameters (starting with a question mark).

Unfortunately, that part of Play code is quite hard-coded in the DBPlugin class which means that you can't add the options that way. You will have to look for a way to alter the options in a later stage.